# ubuntu server guest in vmware and windows 10 connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, routing, vmware

I am learning about networking.  I would like to connect my window 10 pc to ubuntu server 16.10 which is hosted as guest in vmware workstation 12 virtual machine. However I am not able to connect them. these are my configurations.

```
 this is my windows 10 configuration
 Wireless-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

 Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : 2a01:c23:8415:9e00:18ea:ee9:f847:5981
 IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:c23:8415:9e00:1c5b:a0a7:7e3e:42b
 Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : 2a01:c23:8415:9e00:a0c6:27b8:a0c4:af13
 Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : 2a01:c23:8415:9e00:f49e:9ab1:581a:c3ce
 Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::1c5b:a0a7:7e3e:42b%12
 IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.28
 Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1


 ubuntu server 16.10

 auto ens30
 iface ens30 inet static
 Address 192.168.1.20
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I am using NAT connection. ping any of them is not working

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: For the guest use a bridged connection, not NAT. https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html